# Chrome audio muted in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, audio

Updated from Ubuntu 12.04 -> 12.10 -> 13.04.  Everything went smooth except for Chrome. Chrome has no audio, period, from YouTube or anything.

If I open up Pulse Audio volume controller I can see Chrome show up when I start a video but the volume indicators are not moving.

All other sounds work perfect, all other apps play sound no problem. This is entirely Chrome which is why I am at a loss.

---

**Updates**:
Reinstalling Chrome didn't help.

Running this command cleaned up a bunch but did not help:

```
 sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"
```

I tried the following, found to help people on 13.04 with audio issues but did not solve this:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
 sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
 sudo alsa force-reload
```

Only important update:

When I restart Chrome and start a video I hear maybe half a second of audio from the video then silence. Pulse volume controller even shows volume for that half second then goes silent.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"`

Comment: I tried both to no avail.  See updates.

Comment: Okay I fixed it... Go to chrome://plugins and I disabled the flash plugin, restarted browser, enabled flash plugin, restart browser, audio appears to be working.

Comment: @Halsafar If you are still out there and active, please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely a difficult one to debug. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and discovered the same issue--audio on everything else OK except Google Chrome. I am also on an LDAP enabled network auth with home exported from another machine, so I am having my share of permissions issues on `~/config/google-chrome`.

But what worked for me is to **remove** `~/.config/google-chrome` completely (back it up before you do anything), and then fire up Google Chrome. Sound then worked magically, so I knew it had to do with my *stale* `~/.config/google-chrome`. So I moved the items from my backup of `~/backup/google-chrome` into the new `~/.config/google-chrome/` and viola! everything as you would expect, sound working flawlessly.

Hope this helps someone.